# Is there a way to disable curve normals by default?

Tags: bezier-curves

Every time I create a new curve and go into edit mode, the default view looks like a centipede, with an excess of arrows to show the curve normal and direction. Although I can disable this in the Shading panel with the curve selected, I'm getting sick of doing so for each curve and was wondering if there is a way to disable it by default. I tried doing it once and saving the start up scene, but this didn't work.

[image]

**Note**: I think it might be possible to change the initial setup for the curve if it is specified in the python code somewhere. However, I had a look around, but couldn't find anything defined in the Python code, so perhaps the setup is handled in the C part of blender :/ If anyone with knowledge of the codebase has some ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 2):

You're right: saving to startup scene doesn't make the change permanent. A workaround I use is changing the Normal Sizes on the same display tab to something smaller and less intrusive.
Then I go to object mode, delete the curve and save as startup file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>. The next time I open blender,  the normal size for displaying curves is how I set it.

Comment: Thanks. This is a helpful tip. However, I want to disable them by default :/

Comment: @MrFlamey  Try making the normal size "0" It will not make the lines go away but it will make the lines very small...