# How can i hide the references lines on a bezier curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

I want to hide all those lines, only keeping the main curve while working, how can i do that?
[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15897/is-there-a-way-to-disable-curve-normals-by-default

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can hide the path normal markings by pressing <kbd>N</kbd> and then finding the *Curve Display* section. Under that un-tick *Normals*. If you were referring to the handles (the red line), then that option is the next checkbox.

[image]

Comment: In 2.8+ the settings seem to be at the bottom of the "overlays" pan.

Comment: @AnthonyBobenrieth Thanks - I've been searching every panel for about a day and a half looking for that.

Comment: @AnthonyBobenrieth okay and so where IS the "overlays" pan…?

Comment: @Tim Two balls icon in top right of a viewport. This should help: https://i.imgur.com/5xUDBut.png