# Bezier curve normal size length

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Is there a way to change the length of the displayed cyrve normal arrows when working with the Bezier curve? I'm using metric for my scene and I'm doing a small cable and this "centipede legs" are just disturbing. Is there a way to change the length?

Comment: I found a solution myself in menu N and the options in Curve Display.

Comment: related: and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15897/is-there-a-way-to-disable-curve-normals-by-default/15905#15905 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39759/hiding-bezier-curve-handles/39761#39761